# jQuery / Javascript - submit form when checkbox is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a page where I display results form database and there are checkboxs which filter ther results. The problem is that I don't want to use submit button because I would like to let the user only click on the checkboxes to get the desired results. So is there anyway using javascript or jquery to submit a form when checkbox is checked with no submit button? if you see on shopping sites there are no submit buttons just the checkboxes..Like that. thanks

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="size" > Size
</form>
```

here is the php

```
<?php if (isset($_POST["size"])){
  //do something
?>
```

Comment: Including your code, and details about what you've tried will help get quality answers. People ARE answering, but they're essentially guessing. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Show us your code, and tell us what you did.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checkbox"/>
    </form> 
    <script type="text/javascript">  
        $(function(){
         $('.checkbox').on('change',function(){
            $('#form').submit();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

OR

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="">
<input type="checkbox" onchange="$('#form').submit();"  name="checkbox" class="checkbox"/>
</form>
```

Comment: It is not working for me.

Comment: @user2510039 did you set the **action=""** and the **method=""** for the <form/> ? also what is the error returned?

Comment: yes I have set the action and method. when I click on the form nothing happens

Comment: click on the form? don't you need click/change the checkbox to submit the form? try checking/unchecking checkbox this is what you asked for @user2510039

Comment: I am sorry what I meant was check the checkbox. does the javascript should be somewhere around the form? I have it inside <head></head>

Comment: @user2510039 http://jsfiddle.net/yav6n/ you can put js everywhere but better to put it on bottom of the page at the very bottom (footer) , do you included jquery library in your page?

Comment: @user2510039 http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_install.asp first load jquery then all the other js

Comment: thanks moved it to the bottom of the form and now it is working. many thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
$(input:name=[checkboxname]).change(function(){

 $('#form').submit();

});
```

alternately

```
 $('#checkboxId').click(function(){

    $('#formId').submit();

  });
```

of course additional parameters can be passed withing the submit() function for ajax, etc.